# Google sheet extract from text the numeric values by using regexextract problem

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Im trying to format correctly numeric vlues from text type to finantial one. Im quite new to google sheets.
The data are from CSV file. Numeric values ar comma and dot separated for egzample: 2,555.00 or 555.00 or with bigger values 123,555.00.
Im using formula regexextract to extract numeric values. From some reason its not working correctly with big numbers correctly. I marked it on picture. It cut big numbers incorectly and cents values.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"[0-9,]+")*1
```

[Bank statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtEfA.png)

Can you please help wit better regex or oter solution that will work for google sheets?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code/error/textual content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste them here as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your given sample, it seems you just need to substitute comma `(,)` then suppress it to numeric value. Try-

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(C2,",","")
```

> `--` to force text to convert number.

[image]